# Is there anyway to check if given XPath is valid in Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, dom, xpath

I have a python code that is extracting some information from a table. But the thing is sometimes the Xpath changes. Right now it only changes between two different XPath's that looks like this:

```
//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span/
```

and the other alternative is a slight change in the table like this:

```
//*[@id='content-primary']/table[2]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span/
```

this is the code that i am using right now to get the information that i need:

```
rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table[3]/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
```

So what i want to do is a check if the given XPath is valid. If it is not i just try the other XPath alternative.

Hope somebody can help me with this problem. Thank you all.

**EDIT1**

```
<table class="clCommonGrid" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Kommande matcher</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:1%;">Tid</th>
                    <th style="width:69%;">Match</th>
                    <th style="width:30%;">Arena</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <dl>
                        <dt class="clNotify">Röd text</dt>
                        <dd> = Ändrad matchtid&nbsp;</dd>
                        <dt><img src="http://svenskfotboll.se/i/u/alert.gif" alt="Röda utropstecknet" /></dt>
                        <dd> = Peka på utropstecknet så visas en notering&nbsp;</dd>
                        <dt><img src="http://svenskfotboll.se/i/widget.gif" alt="Widget" /></dt>
                        <dd><a href="http://gbgfotboll.se/widgets/?scr=cominginleague&amp;ftid=57109">Hämta widget för kommande matcher</a></dd>
                    </dl>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
            <tbody class="clGrid">

        <tr class="clTrOdd">
            <td nowrap="nowrap" class="no-line-through">
                <span class="matchTid"><span>2015-04-17<!-- br ok --> 19:15</span></span>  //This is the date i am checking with first



            </td>
            <td><a href="?scr=result&amp;fmid=2928398">Götene IF - Vårgårda IK </a></td>  // The other information that i need from the table later
            <td><a href="?scr=venue&amp;faid=16484">Sparbanksvallen Götene konstgräs </a> </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: This [solution][1] might help you. In the exception, you can try another file.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889021/valid-xpath-expression

Comment: what do you mean with file? @Vijay

Comment: I'd suggest to construct single XPath that depends more on nodes attributes value (id, class, .etc) rather than having 2 XPaths that depend on nodes positons...

Comment: Is there anyway you could provide an example regarding this situatiom?, i am not so familiar with python or html @har07

Comment: @TimoCengiz If you can post portion of the html, at least from the node with id equals 'content-primary' down to the `<span>` that you want the XPath to return, we may than be able to give a better XPath example that work against the html posted

Comment: True. I will do that as soon as i come home, thank you @har07

Comment: i put up some of the code now. @har07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation i did not need to specify which table to extract the information from. Since the information that i will get is specified with the date that only contains in that table i just used this code and it worked out fine for me:

```
**rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))**
```

now it is just table which means it will go through both tables in the website. Its not maybe a clean solution but works for me..